# How do I access the explain() method and executionStats when using Spring Data MongoDb v2.x?

Tags: spring-data-mongodb

It's time to ask the community. I cannot find the answer anywhere.

I want to create a generic method that can trace all my repository queries and warn me if a query is not optimized (aka missing an index).

With Spring Data MongoDb v2.x and higher and with the introduction of the Document API, I cannot figure out how to access DBCursor and the explain() method.

The old way was to do it like this:
https://enesaltinkaya.com/java/how-to-explain-a-mongodb-query-in-spring/

Any advise on this is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question but wanted to give input from a similar requirement I had in capacity planning for a cosmos Db project using Java Mongo API driver v2.X.

Summarizing [Enes Altınkaya's blog post](https://blog.enesaltinkaya.com/java/how-to-explain-a-mongodb-query-in-spring/). With an `@autowired` MongoTemplate we use **runCommand** to execute server-side db queries by passing a Document object. Getting to an *explain* output we parse a Query or Aggregate object into a new Document object and add the entry `{"executionStats": true}`(or `{"executionStatistics": true}` for cosmos Db). Then wrap it in an another Document using "explain" as the propery.

For Example:

**Query**:

```java
public static Document documentRequestStatsQuery(MongoTemplate mongoTemplate, 
Query query, String collectionName) {
    Document queryDocument = new Document();
    queryDocument.put("find", collectionName);
    queryDocument.put("filter", query.getQueryObject());
    queryDocument.put("sort", query.getSortObject());
    queryDocument.put("skip", query.getSkip());
    queryDocument.put("limit", query.getLimit());
    queryDocument.put("executionStatistics", true);
    Document command = new Document();
    command.put("explain", queryDocument);
    Document explainResult = mongoTemplate.getDb().runCommand(command);
    return explainResult;
  }
```

**Aggregate**:

```java
public static Document documentRequestStatsAggregate(MongoTemplate mongoTemplate, 
Aggregation aggregate, String collection) {
    Document explainAggDocument = Document.parse(aggregate.toString());
    explainAggDocument.put("aggregate", collection);
    explainAggDocument.put("executionStatistics", true);
    Document command = new Document();
    command.put("explain", explainAggDocument);
    Document explainResult = mongoTemplate.getDb().runCommand(command);
    return explainResult;
  }
```

For the actual monitoring, since Service & Repository classes are MongoTemplate abstractions we can use Aspects to capture the query/aggregate execution details as the applications is running.

For Example:

```java
@Aspect
@Component
@Slf4j
public class RequestStats {
  @Autowired
  MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;

  @After("execution(* org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.aggregate(..))")
  public void logTemplateAggregate(JoinPoint joinPoint) {
    Object[] signatureArgs = joinPoint.getArgs();
    Aggregation aggregate = (Aggregation) signatureArgs[0];
    String collectionName = (String) signatureArgs[1];
    Document explainAggDocument = Document.parse(aggregate.toString());
    explainAggDocument.put("aggregate", collectionName);
    explainAggDocument.put("executionStatistics", true);
    Document dbCommand = new Document();
    dbCommand.put("explain", explainAggDocument);
    Document explainResult = mongoTemplate.getDb().runCommand(dbCommand);
    log.info(explainResult.toJson());
  }
  
}
```

Outputs something like below after each execution:

```json
{
                "queryMetrics": {
                    "retrievedDocumentCount": 101,
                    "retrievedDocumentSizeBytes": 202214,
                    "outputDocumentCount": 101,
                    "outputDocumentSizeBytes": 27800,
                    "indexHitRatio": 1.0,
                    "totalQueryExecutionTimeMS": 15.85,
                    "queryPreparationTimes": {
                        "queryCompilationTimeMS": 0.21,
                        "logicalPlanBuildTimeMS": 0.5,
                        "physicalPlanBuildTimeMS": 0.58,
                        "queryOptimizationTimeMS": 0.1
                    },
                    "indexLookupTimeMS": 10.43,
                    "documentLoadTimeMS": 0.93,
                    "vmExecutionTimeMS": 13.6,
                    "runtimeExecutionTimes": {
                        "queryEngineExecutionTimeMS": 1.56,
                        "systemFunctionExecutionTimeMS": 1.36,
                        "userDefinedFunctionExecutionTimeMS": 0
                    },
                    "documentWriteTimeMS": 0.68
                }
// ...
```

I usually log this out into another collection or write to file.